# Using 2.4 GHz microwaves to demonstrate optical polarization

Tags: microwave, hardware

Several educational companies sell kits to demonstrate optical polarization using 3 cm (10 GHz) microwaves emitted from a Gunn diode transmitter and simple grid-like polarizers.

My question is whether it would be possible to set up something similar using 2.4 GHz transmitter/receivers which are very cheap by comparison.

Not looking for yes/no, just an idea of the obstacles to overcome. I *think* the 2.4 GHz waves are already polarized (as are the 3cm waves), but they are hard to control and measure. Is there a DIY solution here?

Comment: sure, if you have a way to transmit waves and a way to measure signal strength. The waves have to be strong enough that you can see the strength.

Comment: @user253751: the question assumes we have 2.4 ghz transmitter. this can transmit a signal across an auditorium so yes the signal is measurable.

Comment: then you can do the experiment and find out. Beware the waves may bounce around the side of the auditorium, etc. and get to the receiver anyway. The receiver is probably be designed to receive quite weak signals. That's why it's good to measure the signal strength and not just whether it is received or not.

Comment: Note that for the most part, the polarization of the transmitted wave is determined by the antenna, not by the transmitter.

Comment: @user253751: you cannot measure polarization with the transmitters out of the box. signal strength is not the only issue.

Comment: @daniel you could use two polarizers for the experiment

Comment: @SteveSh: Assuming you are correct, the wave can be polarized after it leaves the transmitter if necc.

Comment: One issue is collimating/controlling the wave and making suitable polarizers, which I think should have spacing <1/2 the 12.5cm wavelength. The first part is not s trivial problem.Even a microwave oven will leak measurable energy across a room.

Comment: @daniel - Yes, that's usually the way it's done.  The transmitter is "polarization agnostic".  The radiated signal can be made linear (horizontal, vertical, slant), circular, etc just by choosing the appropriate radiator/antenna.

Comment: @SteveSh: Ah, that's helpful. It may be possible to find an antenna to ensure (say) vertical polarization then? That's a start.

Comment: If OP is planning to use the magnetron of a microwave oven as a power source, this is potentially dangerous and should be discouraged.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg: No the OP is not planning to do that. There is no suggestion of this in the question.

Comment: Edmund optics sells optical frequency wire grid polarizers for ~50 USD. If this is for educational purposes could ask them for a discount or reject part. Would avoid the trouble of the transmitter and receiver since you can see visible light attenuation directly.

Comment: @user1850479: have done that. Edmund is a great company. My question is about 2.4 ghz microwave b/c there are specific questions I wish to explore. .

Comment: @daniel - What exactly are you trying to explore?  Is something as simple as transmitting in one polarization, receiving on a different pol, and seeing what the amplitude differences between TH-RH (transmit horizontal, receive horizontal) and TH-RV cases, for example? You can do that by fixing the orientation of the transmit antenna and just rotating the receive antenna.

Comment: @SteveSh: only a little more involved than that. The antenna on this low-power tx/rx pair are simple ~10cm rods and I doubt that simply changing the relative orientations will noticeably change signal strength but I will try that and get back. Thanks.

Comment: @daniel - You really have to be in an anechoic chamber of some sort to see that effect (should have said this in my earlier comment).  The problem is that polarizations get all scrambled when they bounce off things.